# use streamreader find the specific user entry in the text file and display the 5th component in label

Tags: c#

Data was passed from another form which containing a user entry, using Streamreader find the specific user entry in the text file and display the 5th component in the array.

in the login form, I passed the user entry: `seow` into this form, how do I make sure it displays 20, in label3?

in account.txt

```
seow 1111 wen 12345 20 50  
user 1234 user1 12345 70 80
```

C# Code:

```
List<string> user = new List<string>();

private void Balance_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string username;
   username = login.accountname;
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("account.txt");
   string line = "";
   if (user.Contains(username))
   {
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         string[] components = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
         label3.Text = string.Join(" ", components[5]);
       }
       sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: if the string components position ```index[5]``` represents the value 20 then the label should display that value only always

Comment: the problem i am having is the label text did not change, i am wondering is it the user.contains condition wasnt set appropriately. if i remove the condition it will display 70 instead of 20

Comment: that should be an error with your ```String.join``` method

Comment: try this ```string.join('","',components[5])```

Comment: any idea with the modification of my code?

Comment: let me know if that works

Comment: cause it is joined by space, not with a comma, thats the reason the join is used with a space

Comment: did u solve it??? if not avoid that comma and try with  what I have given

Comment: no, it induced an error

Comment: let me clarify one thing what values your ```string[] compnonets``` is having can u show an example

Comment: i resolved already, i should use the declared components to set condition

Comment: ok great glad that u have fixed your error cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive madeit by changing the condition, thanks for the ideas

```
 while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] components = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if( components.Contains(username))
                  {
                     curbal = string.Join(" ", components[5]);
                     label3.Text = curbal;
                     savbal = string.Join(" ", components[6]);
                     label5.Text = savbal;
                   }

            }
            sr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of I have tried

```
string path1 = AppDomainAppPath + "\\Subscribtion\\Subscribe.txt";
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path1);
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 1)
{
  // Process line
  txtcollege.Value = lines[1];
  txtplace.Value = lines[3];
}
file.Close();
```

[image: txt file]

ouput
[image: output]